# Clojure unquote '(1 2 (+ 1 2))

Tags: clojure

How should I unquote in the following:

```
(def a '(1 2 (+ 1 2)))
```

So that it evaluates to:

```
(1 2 3)
```

Doing a:

```
(def a '(1 2 ~(+ 1 2)))
```

evaluates as below in the REPL:

```
(1 2 (clojure.core/unquote (+ 1 2)))
```

I know I can do a:

```
(list 1 2 (+ 1 2))
```

But I was wondering whether there might be some syntax for the purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `` ` `` instead of `'`. Unquoting does not work with `'`.